# Is there a cmd command to stop running django python server on localhost?

Tags: python, django, cmd

I simply ran the server on local host using the simple cmd command, but I can't seem to find the command for stopping the service. Is it something really simple I missed? Thanks for help.

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Comment: I believe the server is stopped when the terminal window is closed or when you send CTRL+C When invoked in the way you described.

Answer (score 1):

CTRL+C to interrupt a process in a terminal